# Dynamically Creating a code from a string,executing it to call a form.showdialog() method;

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have managed to create a dynamically created string to compile as a code,it does the basic stuff like MessageBox.Show or create integers,strings etc.Now i want to open an instance of a from from my generated code,how can i achieve that?I used a code i found from the net to start,as stated below.Regards.

```
               string lcCode = this.memoEdit1.Text;

            lcCode = @"
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace {
public class MyClass {

public object DynamicCode(params object[] Parameters) {
" + lcCode + 
"return (object) DateTime.Now;"+
"}   }    }";




            ICodeCompiler loCompiler = new CSharpCodeProvider().CreateCompiler();
            CompilerParameters loParameters = new CompilerParameters();

            // ref assmbles lazım ekle,mssql vs.
            loParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            loParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");



            loParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

            // yuru
            CompilerResults loCompiled = loCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(loParameters, lcCode);


            #region errör
            if (loCompiled.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                string lcErrorMsg = "";

                // erörrler
                lcErrorMsg = loCompiled.Errors.Count.ToString() + " Errors:";
                for (int x = 0; x < loCompiled.Errors.Count; x++)
                    lcErrorMsg = lcErrorMsg + "\r\nLine: " + loCompiled.Errors[x].Line.ToString() + " - " +
                        loCompiled.Errors[x].ErrorText;

                MessageBox.Show(lcErrorMsg + "\r\n\r\n" + lcCode, "Erörrz", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                return;
            }

            # endregion

            //this.memoEdit1.Text = lcCode;

            Assembly loAssembly = loCompiled.CompiledAssembly;

            // Object dinamik !!!!1!1  o yüzden obje kalsın!


            object loObject = loAssembly.CreateInstance("MyNamespace.MyClass");
            if (loObject == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Class error");
                return;
            }

            object[] loCodeParms = new object[1];
            loCodeParms[0] = "Test";

            try
            {
                object loResult = loObject.GetType().InvokeMember("DynamicCode",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, loObject, loCodeParms);





                //MessageBox.Show("Method Call Result:\r\n\r\n" + loResult.ToString(), "Sonuç", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception loError)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(loError.Message, "Erörrz", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

Comment: A quick addition: if i run the code lets say; var form = new form2(); form.show dialog for ex,it says it cannot find the instance of the form, i guess thats because,since this is a dynamically generated code in the memory, it can not find the references,so is there way to show the references to this code?

Comment: You are going to have to either generate the code for the form class or add a reference to an assembly that contains the form class.

Comment: OK,so it seems; I have to add my own references manually to my complier,so i just scanned my whole folder for dlls, exes etc and added all to my references with a foreach loop,and now it seems to work...

Cheers.